# How can I organize views in Eclipse for one and two monitors?

Tags: multiple-monitors, eclipse

I use Eclipse with two monitors and several detached views. This is very useful so you can watch the console output on a seperated screen.

My problem occurs if I switch to one monitor. The console view appears in the middle of nowhere, probably where the second monitor was. I cannot move the view, and restarting Eclipse does nothing.

Does anyone have a simple approach to move the views back *without* resetting the perspective?

Comment: Already on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318940/any-tips-on-how-to-organize-eclipse-environment-on-multiple-monitors

Comment: Systech: Sorry, but it does not answer my question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can find is to create a separate perspective for using with a single monitor. Then you can switch between a single-monitor and multi-monitor perspectives as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use [old eclipse version: 3.7.2 indigo-SR2](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/indigo/sr2). I don't see this issue on 3.7.2. After switching off second monitor, it views don't appears on first monitor.